# Export Data Feed for Forms Library (Infopath) for Reporting

Tags: infopath, reports, forms-library, powerpivot

I need to create reports based on the Infopaths submitted in the forms library. This library will act as data source for my reports (reports like how many forms are submitted / some pie charts etc.)
What I'm doing here to find, if forms library can be pulled in Excel 2010 PowerPivot as a data source (just like any other SP list / library using Export as Data Feed), if so several interactive reports can be created.

I can do PowerPivot reports (Power Views) for other lists / libraries where I can see the "*Export as Data Feed*", but not Forms library. Am I missing something here or it's just by design and forms library is no supported as data source for PowerPivot ?

... Any Advise or Comments ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Form libraries have the Export as feed option. You'll most likely need to make sure any fields you want to report on are promoted fields and construct a view that contains all the required information. Then Export it to Excel so it generates an IQY file and use that as a datasource.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have fields promoted and a view which I use that setup as a fallback option. 

My understanding is you can pull a list into a Powerpivot excel using REST API interface (.../_vti_bin/listdata.svc/FormsLibrary). I can see the ATOM Feed output for Forms library on the browser, but error when I use same rest api url for Powerpivot as data feed option. That is my question, can we do pull forms library into a powerpivot just like other lists / libraries, because every data storage / list thing in SharePoint is fundamentally a list ?